# How to know the error / exception when file upload download transfer state is FAILED

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using transfer manager available in AWS SDK for file upload and download.Upload and download method returns Upload , Download Object respectively. I am using the isDone() method to check if the upload/download is finished.Now isDone() method returns true even when TransferState is FAILED. I need to know the error or exception that has occurred which has caused this failure. How can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition and [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.html#isDone--);

> `isDone` Returns true if this transfer is finished (i.e. `completed successfully`, `failed`, or was `canceled`). Returns false if otherwise.

What you may use;

> `waitForCompletion`: Waits for this transfer to complete. This is a blocking call; the current thread is suspended until this transfer completes. details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.html#waitForCompletion--)

Maybe this one

> `waitForException`: Waits for this transfer to finish and returns any error that occurred, or returns null if no errors occurred. This is a blocking call; the current thread will be suspended until this transfer either fails or completes successfully. details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.html#waitForException--)

Both are `blocking` calls but throws exceptions which includes details.

Comment: Just a query on this...if the transfer state is failed then does it not means that exception has already occurred....Or in this case waitForCompletion or waitForException will return immediately with exception and it's details..!!

Comment: even the transfer state failed - in aws side their job `is done` (it is done for them even it fails) - `waitFor`.... methods will not return immediately but when the exception occurs but they will throw `InterruptedException` or some others such as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException.html or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html?is-external=true (i am not sure whether i got what you mean) @whysoseriousson

Comment: I have function F in which i am calling transfermanager.upload . F returns the upload object which is then checked in another function g . Now in g  i can see that the transfer state is Failed. Now lets say in g i call waitForException() would that be right and can i obtain the exception which cased the transfer state to Failed.
P.S. I am clear that isDone would be true when transfer state is FAILED,SUCCESS or CANCELLED.

Comment: @whysoseriousson https://prnt.sc/su2ggg  https://prnt.sc/su2hzy https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#upload-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File- according to here - within the try/catch you will capture that exception within the `g`.

Answer (score 0):

For file upload you can check errors in this way, I'm copying code in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html#transfer-manager-upload) and adding exception handling:

```
public String uploadFile(S3TransferManager transferManager, String bucketName,
          String key, String filePath) {
    UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest = UploadFileRequest.builder()
              .putObjectRequest(b -> b.bucket(bucketName).key(key))
              .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
              .source(Paths.get(filePath))
              .build();

    FileUpload fileUpload = transferManager.uploadFile(uploadFileRequest);

    try {
        CompletedFileUpload uploadResult = fileUpload.completionFuture().join();
        System.out.println("Successfully uploaded file");
        return uploadResult.response().eTag();
    } catch(CancellationException e) {
        System.out.println("File upload was cancelled for file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(CompletionException e) {
        System.out.println("File upload completed with error for file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ""; //some error
}
```

For download you can use the same exception handling. I responded a question here [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77344031/file-is-not-completely-downloaded-using-amazon-s3-transfer-manager-aws-sdk-java/78036735#78036735)