# File is not completely downloaded using Amazon S3 Transfer Manager AWS SDK Java 2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm facing a strange issue with the API I am trying to build, specifically when trying to download a file. Here's what's happening:

When I run the API on my local machine and request to download a file, everything works fine and the whole file gets downloaded without any problems. However, when I try to make the same request on staging where the API is deployed, only a small part of the file is downloaded.

The Amazon S3 async client is set up the same way for both my local environment and the staging environment, except for the credentials provider object. we use the S3 Transfer Manager to handle file downloads

here is the code to download a file

```
public Long downloadFile(
      String key, String downloadedFileWithPath) {
    if (key == null || key.isEmpty() || downloadedFileWithPath == null
      || downloadedFileWithPath.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "key and downloadedFileWithPath should have a value.");
    }
    DownloadFileRequest downloadFileRequest =
        DownloadFileRequest.builder()
            .getObjectRequest(b -> b.bucket(bucketName).key(key))
            .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
            .destination(Paths.get(downloadedFileWithPath))
            .build();

    FileDownload downloadFile = transferManager.downloadFile(
        downloadFileRequest);

    CompletedFileDownload downloadResult = downloadFile.completionFuture()
        .join();
    return downloadResult.response().contentLength();


  }
```

Comment: This is basically the documented AWS [download a file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html#transfer-manager-download) example. Where is this deployed? EC2? Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

I'm responding this question because AWS documentation is incomplete here and I was looking for hours how to handle download errors. The next one with the same problem, can have this info available.

That is the code that AWS documentation suggests. It is OK. The problem of that code is that it doesn't do any error handling. So, if there is an error you have zero information.

You should write this code inside a try-catch block:

```
CompletedFileDownload downloadResult = downloadFile.completionFuture()
        .join();
```

This is how it should be written to handle or log errors:

```
try {
    CompletedFileDownload downloadResult = fileDownload.completionFuture().join();
    System.out.println("Successfully downloaded file with content length: " + downloadResult.response().contentLength());
    return downloadResult.response().contentLength();
} catch(CancellationException e) {
    System.out.println("File download was cancelled");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(CompletionException e) {
    System.out.println("File download completed with error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return -1; //Some error
```

This will not solve the error you are having (actually you were having 6 months ago and I hope it's fixed by now) but it will let you understand what error you're having and then you can solve it.